# JMeter response time decreases after the first run of test plan

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I have a test plan setup which I am using on my web application. It is pretty simple , a user logs in and then navigates through some of the pages. Everything's working fine except the fact that whenever I run the test plan for the first time(say first time after restarting the web application server) the average response time recorded are around 18000ms but in the susequent runs it is always around 3000ms until i restart the server. I just want to know why this is happening. Pardon me, I am newbie to this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Variation is high, generally you get better results in subsequent runs because of caching but not this much. to check whether is it because of caching or something else, run it with parameterized values everytime. If you get so much improvement in response time because of caching, its not wrong or something you should worry about but just be sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start to exclude some part of test plan and try again. If this response time does not decrase then you can focus your web application server thread pool size. If it is very small and your Jmeter test plan needs more than this size then application server try to create new threads. When you increase your min thread pool size on app server the response time is still high then need to focus what your test plan does. By the way, I want to have a look at your test plan if you share.

Comment: what i am trying to say is that when i run the test plan for the first time it takes 6 times the duration when i run it subsequent times.. I want to know why there is so much difference in the response time between the first time and the subsequent times..Is it related to caching or something which happens may be when i run the same test plan again.

Comment: In general my question is **does executing the same test plan again consecutively can give this much variation in results i.e first time avg. response time=18000ms and second time avg response time=3000ms?**

Comment: These different results maybe as expected if your request sent over HTTP and your network topology can have a kind of load balancer layer which caches the response for previous requests. But this is a just one comment. There can be different reason for your question. It would be useful to see your test plan.